# Trying to compress a string

Tags: string, loops, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a string, some like this 'aaaabbbcc' to compress into 'a4b3c2'.
i already have it counting the 'a' and compressing right, like this 'a4', but how do i continue on? here is my program:

```
     def compress(estring):
        cstring= ''
        ct2=0
        npos = estring[ct2]

        ct=0
        for char in estring:
            if char == npos:
                ct+=1
                ct2+=1

        cstring += npos + str(ct)
        return cstring
```

Comment: For a start, you need to indent your code properly. Without that, it's nonsense.

Comment: fix your indentation please, it is python...BTW, if your string is `python`, the compressed string would be `p1y1t1h1o1n1`?  It is not compressing.

Comment: yea it must have pasted funny

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It uses speed advantage of iteration(not indexing) and runs in linear time.

```
def compress(string):
    prevchar = string[:1]
    cnt = 1
    result = []
    for char in string[1:]:
        if char == prevchar:
            cnt += 1
        else:
            result.append(prevchar+str(cnt))
            cnt = 1
        prevchar = char
    return ''.join(result) + prevchar + str(cnt)
```

I've tested it with timeit, and it seems to run a little bit faster than solutions above. The disadvantage is that my solution is less pythonic:

```
import timeit
avg = lambda x: sum(x) / len(x)

avg(timeit.repeat(
      stmt = lambda: compress('aaaabbbcc'),
      repeat = 100,
      number = 1000))
```

Gives me 24.7 ms on my machine, while others are in range 28 - 46

It's also generic enough to be used not only with chars but also strings:

```
compress(['ba','ba','ba','boon','boon'])
#Gives 'ba3boon2'
```

Comment: appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to split your string into repeated parts and then create a new string counting these parts, for example:

```
import re


REPETITIONS_REGEXP = re.compile(r'(.)(\1*)')  # match any char and its repetitions

def compact(data):    
    # Get a list with chars and repetions, like [('a', 'aaa'), ('b', 'bb'), ...]
    result = REPETITIONS_REGEXP.findall(data)
    # Create a new string with "char" + (its repetitions + 1)
    return ''.join(['{}{}'.format(x, len(y) + 1) for (x, y) in result])

print compact('aaaabbccc')  # will print 'a4b2c3'
```

Comment: appreciate the help!

Comment: If my post completely answer your question, than please mark it as the answer. ;)

Answer (score -1):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will do all the work for you:

```
s = 'aaaabbbcc'
from itertools import groupby

print("".join([k+str(sum(1 for _ in v)) for k, v in groupby(s)]))
a4b3c2
```

if you have to use a function,keep track of the last char, yield the char and the current count  when you encounter a char that is not the same as the previous one then reset the count and continue:

```
def compress(s):
    it = iter(s)
    prev, i = next(it), 0
    for ch in s:
        if ch != prev:
            yield prev + str(i)
            i = 0
        prev = ch
        i += 1
    yield prev + str(i)

print("".join(compress(s)))
```

Output is the same:

```
a4b3c2
```

Comment: appreciate the help!